# It’s a weekend. / It’s the weekend

Tags: phrase-meaning, articles

As I see it, both versions are used [[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=It%E2%80%99s%20a%20weekend%2CIt%E2%80%99s%20the%20weekend&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&corpus=26&smoothing=50&case_insensitive=true)]. But I can't clearly understand the difference. Feel free to provide some examples.

> **It’s a weekend.**
>
> **It’s the weekend.**

P.S. I read on the internet that the first one is used when we speak about a calendar date, but the second one - about today's weekend, or some certain weekend. Is that right? Are there any others points in using the above mentioned sentences with a/the article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with Ngram is that its numeric approach says nothing about context: what appears rare in general may be common in specific contexts.

In many cases, there is little or no **significant** difference between “a weekend” and “the weekend.”

> It was a weekend so we went to the beach.

> It was the weekend so we went to the beach.

Both sentences convey the same basic thought: they were not days that required us at work so we elected to use our free time by going to the beach. Technically, in the first case with “a,” we are not trying to specify exactly which weekend. In the second case with “the,” we are either referring to a week previously specified or to specific days of the week. But the difference in meaning is inconsequential in these examples.

In a different context, where we are referring to specific days of a specific week, “the” is grammatically required.

> His wife was killed the weekend immediately after their wedding.

is idiomatic.

> His wife was killed a weekend immediately after their wedding

is not idiomatic. There was only one weekend immediately after that specific wedding, and it is that specific weekend that is relevant.

Comment: What about my P.S.? Is that right that only the first version is used when we speak about a calendar date? For example, Today is August, 29. It's a weekend. (not "It's the weekend.")

Comment: This is not a rule. “Today is August 29th; it’s a weekend” is probably the more common, but “Today is August 29th; it’s the weekend, at long last” is quite idiomatic. I tried to explain in my answer that the distinction, when it is consequential, depends on context, not some mechanical rule.